# How to create a staked ORDERED area chart in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, area-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked ordered area chart (emphasis on "ordered") in D3.js.

My current chart is unordered and looks like this:

[image]

But I'm trying to create something more like this (copied from https://datavizproject.com/data-type/stacked-ordered-area-chart/):

[image]

In my example (the one with the horrible colors), the blue area should start at the top of the stack and end in the middle. I'm not sure if d3.js's "stacked area chart" is the best way to approach the problem. **Am I barking up the wrong tree here?**

## UPDATE:

I ended up hacking one together with d3 and python using area plots (ignore the axes, they're just for general magnitude reference):

[image]

Comment: I'm do not understand.  Both your chart and example chart seem ordered the same way.  Largest stack on bottom, next largest on top of that, etc...  You want to reverse that order so that largest is on top?

Comment: difficult to help you wirhout code and to understant whitout  some explanation

Comment: @Mark, The specific kind of stacked ordered area chart I'm trying to create is shown in the second example I shared. To clarify the idea: which color is on top should change as you move from left to right. To start (left), the blue area shoudd be on the bottom. Then (as we move right) the blue area should be on top. In the end (right), the blue area sholud be in the middle.

Comment: @Frenchy, My question wasn't really about fixing or providing a complete solution, but rather pointing me in the right direction. Are stacked area charts the right approach to obtain a plot like the second one I shared? or perhaps there's a better way to generate this type of plot (stacked ordered chart where the order changes as you move from left to right as in the example I provided).

Comment: I understand now.  It's an interesting idea/chart.  I've don't think `d3` has anything like that out "of the box".

Comment: @Mark Yeah, I haven't been able to find any information on this kind of chart in D3. I'm starting to think the best approach might be to draw paths and strategically color the areas between them.

Comment: By the way, I think the actual name of this type of chart might be "sorted stream".